# How to store data from service bus to azure tables?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I want to store data received via topic to Azure tables.
I use Azure functions for that.

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("simple_test_topic", "stt_subscription", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]string mySbMsg,
        [Table("RoomBasicInformation")] CloudTable outputTable, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
        RoomEntry re = new RoomEntry(){ PartKey = "hpk", RoomId = "13", Temperature = "10"};
        var operation = TableOperation.Insert(re);
        await outputTable.ExecuteAsync(operation);
    }
}

public class RoomEntry : TableEntity
{
    public string PartKey { get; set; }
    public string RoomId { get; set; }
    public string Temperature { get; set; }
}
```

But after executing it in visual studio I get

> mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Function1.
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The remote server returned an error:
>   (400) Bad Request.

Comment: Can you share the definition of `RoomEntry` class? Please edit your question and include it there.

Comment: Added RoomEntry class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` of `TableEntity`.

[Add an entity to a table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet#add-an-entity-to-a-table)

Modify `RoomEntity` to initialize those values:

```
public class RoomEntry : TableEntity
{
    public RoomEntry() 
    {
    }

    public RoomEntry(string partitionKey, string roomId) 
    {
        this.PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        this.RowKey = roomId;
    }

    public string RoomId => this.RowKey;
    public string Temperature { get; set; }
}
```

You don't need `PartKey` property `TableEntity` already has one for that.

Also modify `RommEntity` initialization in Azure Function to:

```
var roomEntry = new RoomEntry("hpk", "13") { Temperature = "10" };
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!